# unlist a list of data.tables with list index

Tags: r, data.table

I have a list of data.tables and I was looking to bind them together with a new column with the list index. I've currently used the `rbindlist()` from data.tables, But I'd like to retain the information of its list index. Can you help me do this?

```
set.seed(1)
x1<- data.table(x = LETTERS, y = runif(26))
x2<- data.table(x = LETTERS, y = runif(26))
l1 <- list(x1, x2)
#  head(x1)
#    x         y
# 1: A 0.2655087
# 2: B 0.3721239
# 3: C 0.5728534
# 4: D 0.9082078
# 5: E 0.2016819
# 6: F 0.8983897

#  head(x2)
#    x          y
# 1: A 0.01339033
# 2: B 0.38238796
# 3: C 0.86969085
# 4: D 0.34034900
# 5: E 0.48208012
# 6: F 0.59956583
```

expected result

```
  x         y  g
  A 0.2655087  1
  B 0.3721239  1
  C 0.5728534  1
  D 0.9082078  1
  E 0.2016819  1
  F 0.8983897  1
        .
        .
        .
  A 0.01339033 2
  B 0.38238796 2
  C 0.86969085 2
  D 0.34034900 2
  E 0.48208012 2
  F 0.59956583 2
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: `rbindlist(l1, idcol='g')` ?  I guess the `idcol` option is still in the `v.1.9.6`

Comment: Ah! crap! I haven't been looking into the documentation enough! Thanks!

Comment: @theArun feel free to self answer, there may be future readers coming to your question. akrun doesn't need more SO points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @akrun points outs `idcol` is available in `data.tables` from `v.1.9.6`

```
rbindlist(l1, idcol = 'g')
```

Comment: extra clarification -- if you want the values of `g` to be other than `1`, ..., `length(l1)`, make sure `l1` is named. `g` will be populated with the names of the list element corresponding to where it came from.